# контент оцентровывается, несмотря на justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css

justify-content: space-between не разбрасывает элементы по контейнеру, хотя до этого я всегда так писала и все работало. Теперь логотип и меню стоят друг под другом по центру. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что же не так.

как выглядит страница
[image: как выглядит страница]

html
[image: html]

css
[image: css]

обнуление css
[image: обнуление css]

```css
@import url('null.css');

.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*------------------------МЕНЮ-------------------------*/
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <a href="" class="logo"><img src='img/logo.png'></a>
                <div class="nav">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link">NEWSLETTER</a>
                  <a href="" class="nav-link">COMMUNITY</a>
                  <a href="" class="nav-link">SHOP</a>
                  <a href="" class="nav-link">CONTACT US</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас стили написаны в header, а родитель контента, который надо разнести - .header-inner, вот к нему и применяйте.

Comment: Вот я балда) Спасибо большое!)